# Ruby: convert unix timestamp to date

Tags: ruby, datetime, unix-timestamp

```
irb> dt = Time.now.utc
=> 2012-04-26 10:47:01 UTC

irb> dti = dt.to_i
=> 1335437221
```

Now, how to convert `dti` back to Date/Time ?

Comment: Should be `Time.now.utc`...

Comment: @user1147688: You are right. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use [`Time.at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-at).

```
Time.at(1335437221)
# => 2012-04-26 12:47:01 +0200
```

Comment: Time.at(1335437221).utc Thank you.